# Capybara cannot find fields in feature test

Tags: rspec, capybara

can you please help with this problem?

Capybara cannot find the fields for "article[title]" and "article[body]", in the following feature test:

```
feature "Creating Articles" do

scenario "A user creates a new article" do
    visit '/'

    click_link("New Article")
    fill_in "article[title]",     with: "title"
    fill_in "article[body]",      with: "article body"
    click_button "Create Article"

    expect(page).to have_content "title"
    expect(page).to have_content "article body"

end
```

Both fields show up in the pages source code as `<input class="form-control" type="text" name="article[title]" id="article_title">` and `<textarea class="form-control" name="article[body]" id="article_body" cols="60" rows="12"></textarea>`

but RSpec keeps showing this error.

```
   Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find field "article[title]"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since you have an id defined on both why not try:

fill_in "article_title", with: "title" & fill_in "body", with: "article body"

Comment: @orion `fill_in` will find visible elements by id, name, or placeholder attributes or associated label text so swapping to the id won't make any difference.  @rstreet  Is the HTML you show from when running in the test env or from the development env??  If the dev env - add `sleep 5; puts page.html` after the `click_link("New Article")` (the 2nd one - not sure why you are clicking it twice though) and see what the actual page source in the test environment is.  Odds are the field you think is there isn't or it's being hidden.

Comment: @Thomas Walpole. I had a factory and sign_in method that wasn't included in my code above(I thought it was redundant). After I added "sleep 5; puts page.html", it helped me see the problem, which was the fact that Capybara  wasn't able to get passed sign_in page due to wrong method in my factory. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score -1):

You may have better luck using the id for the `fill_in` descriptor.  `fill_in` uses descriptors for its argument, so either of these forms should work:

```
fill_in "article_title",     with: "title"
fill_in "article_body",      with: "article body"
```

or

```
fill_in "id=article_title",     with: "title"
fill_in "id=article_body",      with: "article body"
```

See this [Selenium Tutorial](https://newcircle.com/bookshelf/selenium_tutorial/locators) for a useful description of the various descriptors.  I keep this bookmarked for situations like yours.

Comment: Greg, the problem was in my factory which wasn't included in the code above. Thanks for the reference!